# Help me installing ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I looked up guides to install ubuntu, but they all say that you can choose the option: "install along windows". But The option is long gone, so i read... .
Now i shrinked my windows partition, and get a new extra partition. When i install ubuntu using a usb device, everything goes well, but when i need to choose a partition to install ubuntu on, i can't use the partition i created because it's not usable... . So i think i have to format the partition but i don't know how.

Can someone help me?

P.S. :  The main goal is to run a dualboot system. I'm using windows7

Answer (score 0):

In  dual boot setup. If you wanted to install the second OS then in some partition then the partition has to be an unallocated space. Use disk management to delete the volume you wanted install and have it as unallocated one and you can select that unallocated space during installations.

Comment: thats what i did, but i couldn't install... i'm gonna try again and then i come back here.

Comment: It said that that partition didn't have a basic filingsystem...